# Apache camel servlet stream closed after split()

Tags: apache-camel

I need to post a JSON Camel Servlet, then duplicate the message and split the list. Process each splitted message and finally aggregate and return the servlet response.

However, as soon as the splitter is introduced in the route, I see the Input Stream is being closed and the Servlet cannot write the response back.

Please note that stream caching is enabled as well.

```
from("servlet:sample")
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Message Received: JSON RQ")
                .to("direct:samplejson");
from("direct:samplejson")
    .streamCaching()
    .setHeader("sampleId", simple("${id}"))
    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, SampleID in Header: ${header.sampleId}")
    .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, Sample.class)
    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Converted to JSON: ${body.toString}")
    .process("sampleProcessor")
    .split().body().streaming()
        .choice()
        .when().method("sampleProcessor", "isTypeA")
            .marshal().jacksonxml(Sample.class)
        .endChoice()
        .otherwise()
            .marshal().jacksonxml(Sample.class)
    .end()
    .aggregate(SampleAggregationStrategy).header("sampleId").completionSize(2).completionTimeout(1000L)
    .to("direct:samplexml");
from("direct:samplexml").marshal().jacksonxml(List.class).log("FINISHED PROCESSING");
```

Exception:

```
2017-06-12 12:22:25,311 [apr-8080-exec-2] INFO  route1                         - FINISHED PROCESSING
2017-06-12 12:22:25,321 [apr-8080-exec-2] ERROR CamelHttpTransportServlet      - Error processing request
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:372) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:156) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.camel.util.IOHelper.copy(IOHelper.java:196) ~[camel-core-2.19.0.jar:2.19.0]
        at org.apache.camel.http.common.DefaultHttpBinding.copyStream(DefaultHttpBinding.java:432) ~[camel-http-common-2.19.0.jar:2.19.0]
        at org.apache.camel.http.common.DefaultHttpBinding.doWriteDirectResponse(DefaultHttpBinding.java:496) ~[camel-http-common-2.19.0.jar:2.19.0]
        at org.apache.camel.http.common.DefaultHttpBinding.doWriteResponse(DefaultHttpBinding.java:395) ~[camel-http-common-2.19.0.jar:2.19.0]
        at org.apache.camel.http.common.DefaultHttpBinding.writeResponse(DefaultHttpBinding.java:322) ~[camel-http-common-2.19.0.jar:2.19.0]
        at org.apache.camel.http.common.CamelServlet.doService(CamelServlet.java:210) [camel-http-common-2.19.0.jar:2.19.0]
        at org.apache.camel.http.common.CamelServlet.service(CamelServlet.java:74) [camel-http-common-2.19.0.jar:2.19.0]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [servlet-api.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) [catalina.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) [catalina.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [catalina.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [catalina.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [catalina.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616) [catalina.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521) [catalina.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2500) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2489) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.30]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_74]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_74]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.30]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_74]
```

If I remove the splitter and aggregator, I see the Servlet response coming back.

Many Thanks in advance for all the help provided!.

Comment: Have you tried a vanilla split and aggregate? Which version are you using?

Comment: Was trying to implement my solution based on the Composed message processor pattern described on Camel site. I tried both splitter only version as well as separate aggregator. In both cases, I see the stream is closed. I also debugged the camel code. Basically, the DefaultHttpBinding obj that writes the servlet response back receives an exchange with the **"out"** from the step before the split().

Answer (score 0):

See the Composted Message Processor EIP pattern (http://camel.apache.org/composed-message-processor.html) and the example that uses *splitter only* which allows you to do a fork/join in the same unit of work, and be able to return a response in the servlet. The *splitter only* supports an `AggregationStrategy` you can configure where you aggregate the response. In other words do not use both splitter and aggregator, but only splitter.

Comment: Was trying to implement my solution based on the Composed message processor pattern described on Camel site. I tried both splitter only version as well as separate aggregator. In both cases, I see the stream is closed. I also debugged the camel code. Basically, the DefaultHttpBinding obj that writes the servlet response back receives an exchange with the **"out"** from the step before the split().

Comment: @ClauseIbsen I don't see an example that uses Splitter only in the current docs

https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/eips/composed-message-processor.html